# Iterating over jquery objects with accumulator?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm iterating over a collection of objects with $.each and appending a pre-defined attribute of each of them to the page. This works just fine.

```
$(myObjects).each(function(i) {
    var element = $("<tr>").appendTo(tableBody);
    $("<td>").append(this.unitCount).appendTo(element);
});
```

The value that I am appending is a number. I'd like to keep track of these values in an accumulator and return the total to use elsewhere. Like this:

```
var total = 0;
$(myObjects).each(function(i) {
    var element = $("<tr>").appendTo(tableBody);
    $("<td>").append(this.unitCount).appendTo(element);
    var total = total + this.unitCount;
});
```

The problem is that since $(myObjects) is a collection of objects the accumulator variable total isn't recognized inside the loop. (When I call console.log(total) right after the loop is started the value inside recognized). I'd like to use one loop to append the value to the page as well as keep track of the total. Is this possible?

Comment: And where is problem? Just make `var totalBidUnits` global (write `var totalBidUnits = 0;` before `$(statusData).each`) and use it after that

Comment: Sorry, it's unclear to me...

Comment: I hit enter a bit too early. I have been using the accumulator, but iterating over objects with $.each prevents me from using that functionality. This is reflected in the edit.

Comment: `total = total + 1;` (without `var`) works without problem

Comment: That worked well, thank you. I appreciate you helping out with my syntax error.

Comment: Remove the `var` in front of `total` inside the `.each()` loop.  That declares a second local variable which is temporary and overrides the previous one you declared.  Change `var total = total + this.unitCount;` to this: `total = total + this.unitCount;`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's quite slow to create elements inside an each or for loop, instead construct a HTML string representation. Append it once you're done with your data-loop:

**[jsBin demo](http://jsbin.com/qiqifo/3/edit)**

```
var TR = "";
var total = 0;

$.each(myObjects, function() {
   var uc = this.unitCount;
   TR += "<tr><td>"+ uc +"</td></tr>";
   total += uc;
});

tableBody.append(TR).append("<tr><td>TOTAL: "+ total +"</td></td>");
```